# Cannot run Maven on Jenkins with Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

I am struggling to get a simple maven project running on Jenkins, which runs on my new Ubuntu server (16.04.)

I have installed Jenkins onto an Ubuntu, installed Maven and JDK.

I can connect to bitbucket and access my remote repository and get hold of my code. However, when I try to build I get the message

```
cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/var/snap/jenkins/workspace/project") no such file or directory
```

I have added $JAVA_HOME and $MAVEN_HOME to my /etc/environment as variables and also into my path.

I have looked at the Global Tool Configuration, but this seems to be no help.

When I set the Maven installer to point at Maven home I get  a message 
    /usr/share/maven is not a directory on the jenkins master

When I try to get Jenkins to install maven for me I get

```
Failed to install <truncated>apache-maven-3.5.3.bin.zip to /var/snap/jenkins/6/tools
...
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must not be empty
```

I think I have hit a dead end. What could I be missing, or how can I get past these obstacles ?

Many Thanks

Comment: is that for all the same user ? jenkins installs his own user, which might not have access to mvn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has taken a long time to get to the bottom of this.

By default the

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

seems to install a **Snap** version of Jenkins.

This **snap** version holds data in different locations (which is why I struggled to find the initialAdminpassword

Additionally, the snap setup only has a JRE, which cannot be overridden to a JDK, and therefore does not seem to work properly with Maven.

Eventually, I completely uninstalled Jenkins, and then followed the instructions on the official Jenkins site: 
  https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/

This overrides the base apt-get packages, and points to the jenkins.io packages.

From here on in, it all behaved as per the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration.  I always elect to have Jenkins install and manage Maven, vs install and bring my own.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but as I stated in my original question, when I try this exact step I get the message:
` Failed to install <truncated>apache-maven-3.5.3.bin.zip to /var/snap/jenkins/6/tools
...
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must not be emptyFailed to install <truncated>apache-maven-3.5.3.bin.zip to /var/snap/jenkins/6/tools
...
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must not be empty`

Comment: I follow.  Sorry about that, I have a tendency to not finish reading before responding.  What if you install mvn, test it out first locally, then put a symlink in "/var/snap/jenkins/workspace/project"?

Comment: Test out the symlink locally also.